# Ordinal regression - scale with small number of observation per category

Tags: r, regression, survey, ordinal-data

I would like to run a ordinal regression. My dependent variable is a scale from 0 to 6 but the number of observation in each category are not even (my sample size is very small - 70) and in some categories there are only few observations. Should I create less category such as low, medium, high? In that case, how do I split the categories?

Thanks a lot